# Fuse Console not starting

Tags: apache-karaf, fuse

I have done a clean install fuse on karaf at

```
C:\esb\redhatfusekaraf\fuse-karaf-7.8.0.fuse-780038-redhat-00001
```

FUSE_HOME environment variable is set to this directory.

I have OpenJDK installed at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.282.8-hotspot
```

PATH and JAVA_HOME are set properly and tested.

When I run fuse.bat from the above install here is what I get.

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1440]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
C:\Users\MO Tec>%FUSE_HOME%
'C:\esb\redhatfusekaraf\fuse-karaf-7.8.0.fuse-780038-redhat-00001' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\esb\redhatfusekaraf\fuse-karaf-7.8.0.fuse-780038-redhat-00001\bin>fuse
karaf.bat: Ignoring predefined value for KARAF_HOME
Red Hat Fuse starting up. Press Enter to open the shell now...
100% [========================================================================]
Karaf started in 2s. Bundle stats: 12 active, 13 total
```

No Fuse Shell.  Anything else I can look at?

Comment: Which Windows version do you use? Are you using PowerShell or good old `cmd`? Can you `bin\client.bat` later to this instance?

Comment: @grzegorz Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1440] (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Yes good old cmd.  bin/client failed to get the session.

Comment: I found it!!! I tried to use mvn clean install on one of the quickkstarts I got from github.  Maven crashed due to a missing > in the settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a missing ">" in the maven settings.xml  I discovered it trying to run an "mvn clean install" when maven crashed.

I fixed the missing ">" and not only did that command run and build success but the Fuse Console now appears.

[image]